# 2D graph of function in for loop

Tags: maxima

I am a beginner in wxMaxima and I would need to get multiple 2d graph for this function:

> fn (x) = x ^ n, x = <0,1>, n = 1, .., 50

I tried something like this:

```
for n:1 while n <= 50 do(
   plot2d ([x ^ n], [x, 0,1], [plot_format, gnuplot]) $
);
```

but without success. Could anyone help? thank you

Answer (score 1):

`plot2d([e1, e2, e3, ...], ...)` plots multiple expressions `e1`, `e2`, `e3`, .... How about this:

```
makelist (x^n, n, 1, 50);
plot2d (%, [x, 0, 1]);
```

Takes a few seconds to be drawn, and it is kind of cluttered (there are 50 curves in the plot). But it is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve ? 
Your function will return either 0 or 1 regardless of the exponent.

If you just need an example for a plot generating loop try (in wxmaxima):

```
for n:1 thru 5 do
( 
    eq:n*x+n,
    wxplot2d(
             eq,[x,1,10]
            )
);
```

with plot2d you have to save every plot to a file 
(don't forget to generate new file names with concat).

Regards,
IInatas